# Master Theorem with Log n recombination

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, master-theorem

How I understand the master theorem, an algorithm can be defined recursively as:

```
a T(n/b) + O(n^d)
```

Where a is the number of subproblems, n/b is the size of the subproblems, and O(n^d) is the recombination time of the subproblems. Calculating the time complexity of the master theorem goes as follows:

```
T(n) =  { O(n^d)                    if d > log base b of a
        {
        { O(n^d log n)              if d = log base b of a
        {
        { O(n^ (log base b of a) )  if d < log base b of a
```

My question is, what if the recombination time is not expressed in the form O(n^d)? Such as O(2^n) or O(log(n)). How would one determine the time complexity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Master theorem you wouldn't, it only applies to recurrences of a certain form. You say:

> How I understand the master theorem, an algorithm can be defined recursively as:

But this is not entirely accurate - not all algorithms can be defined recursively like that, as you have shown yourself. The Master theorem only applies to those that can be defined like that (more specifically, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) for all the cases it can be applied to).

For other forms, there are other theorems, such as [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra-Bazzi_theorem).